# How to decrypt Cryptcat with key?

Tags: encryption, nc

I have a Pcapng (Wireshark) encrypted file with Cryptcat and I also have the Password, how can I decrypt the file?

Can't find anything relevant.

Only things like: "**Is it Really Secure?**
Not if your enemy knows the secret key, which is hard coded to be ‘metallica’ (use the -k option to change this key)"

But no explanation on why knowing the secret key is not secure or how to decrypt the file...

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this: (a) replaying the data in a pcap (or pcapng) file, and (b) receiving that data with cryptcat to decrypt it.

There are tools such as tcpreplay https://tcpreplay.appneta.com/ which can do (a).  For (b), you can run cryptcat as a listener:

```
cryptcat -l -k PASSWORD -p 4444
```

I have not tested this, but it "should" work.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I opened my Kali and run in two terminals. Terminal (a) I did tcpreplay -i eth0 -tK --loop 5000 --unique-ip NameOfTheFile.pcapng and Terminal (b) I did cryptcat -l -k PASSWORD -p 4444. But no success. It doesn't print anything on Terminal (b). Anything I missed or did wrong in the command?

Comment: The 4444 is the port cryptcat is listening on.  You need to use whatever port the original stream was sent to, so they match up.  You may also need to check the IP the traffic is being sent to is one your cryptcat is listening on, or it won't "see" the traffic you are replaying.  You could look at the pcap file with wireshark or tcpdump or similar to see what thr original traffic "looks like" in terms of IP addresses and port numbers, and then adjust your receiving setup to match.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. Not quite sure I am doing it right. I Changed the port as well but didn't really get what you said about the IP. Source IP is 172.16.0.37 and Destination is 172.16.0.31. Port Source is 40986 and Port Destination is 8989. Are you able to tell me what should I run in Terminal (a) and Terminal (b)?